# Undesirable animation with unwind segue with nested modal view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, unwind-segue

I have the view controllers architecture as shown here[image]

To unwind from `srcVC` to `dstVC`, control-drag a button to an unwind action `exitToImageEditVC:`.[image]

The `srcVC` gets dismissed and `dstVC` appears when I press appropriate button.  But the issue is the unwind animation.  That is I see a partial of the view controller `modalVCA` behind the view controller `srcVC` momentarily as the `srcVC` slides down.  This is undesirable.  The desired result is when `srcVC` slides down, the `modalVCA` should NOT momentarily appears.  Any input is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any architecture :(

Comment: I think this is a bug. I've noticed this too, and it didn't happen in iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to dismiss modalVCA before presenting modalVCB?  Then srcVC would unwind straight to dstVC.

Comment: I can't dismiss `modalVCA` before presenting `modalVCB` because the user has to option to go back to `modalVCA` directly from `modalVCB`.

Comment: could you then dismiss modalVCB and present modalVCA in that case? I guess my overall comment is can the user interface been redesigned to avoid the issue to begin with?  Depends on the content, flow, relationships of the controllers.  If not, you could create a custom unwind segue but it's a bit complicated.  You need to hold onto the srcViewController, dismissVCB without animating, dismissVCA without animating, and then animate the srcViewController off the screen yourself.

Comment: I know what you meant-- dismissing `modalVCB` and then present `modalVCA` is not the option available to me (as per artistic direction).